# Square PoS API limit

Tags: square-connect

What is the actual limit per transaction for Square PoS API?
According to https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5079-best-practices-for-accepting-payment-cards#high-value-transactions it seems to be $50,000.00.
However using as PoC an Android app integrated with Square PoS API I was able to charge more than quantity.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the documented limit for transactions. It can be possible to start a transaction for more but it should fail during authorization, or take more in a non card transaction.